# Swagger does not show mandatory namespaces, is it possible to make Swashbuckle ignore them?

Tags: c#, swagger, swashbuckle

I've imported a WSDL as service reference and generated a Swagger with endpoints. So far so good!
The problem is that when going into the Swagger to try it out, it does not include the namespaces there, but they are mandatory to have to make it to work.

When pasting my XML into the "try it out" window in the Swagger, swashbuckle does not accept it. It never creates the object.

So my question is, is it possible to make Swagger/Swashbuckle ignore namespaces from the model so it can create the object if i paste an XML without namespaces?

Comment: Are you trying to use swashbuckle with a SOAP webservice?